# Spring vs Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Just trying to get my head round Spring and figuring out how I wire up an Oracle connection in xml config file, and now find out I need yet another framework! - Hibernate, this is soooo frustrating as it feels like I'm getting deeper and deeper into more and more frameworks without actually getting what I need done!

I looked at Hibernate and it seems to do similar things to Spring, bearing in mind I just want to do some SQL inserts in Oracle.

I am reluctant and do not have time to learn 2 frameworks - could I get away with just adopting Hibernate for the simple things I need to do?

Comment: I feel your pain, however Spring and Hibernate seem to do pretty different things. I'm finding that that are pretty dependent on each other for certain tasks.

Comment: I recant the previous statement, apparently spring does orm also.

Comment: "I *just* want to do some SQL inserts in Oracle." Famous last words.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> *...could I get away with just adopting Hibernate for the simple things I need to do?*

Yes

Hibernate is for ORM ( object relational mapping ) that is, make your objects persistent to a RDBMS.

Spring goes further. It may be used also as a AOP,  Dependency Injector, a Web Application and ORM among other things.

So if you only need ORM, just use Hibernate. Time will come when you need Spring, and you will learn it then.

Here's an architectural view of Spring:

[image: spring]

And this is Hibernate:

[image: hibernate]

Answer (score 12):

Spring and Hibernate are totally different frameworks for different problems. Spring is a huge framework with many many features, Hibernate is an O/R bridge.

I would recommend using plain old JDBC in your case ('just some SQL inserts in Oracle').

Comment: Yes, the only thing Spring doesn't have is its own VM, which will probably be added soon won't it? ;)

Comment: The funny thing is that Spring is said to be lightweight, even though it is such a large framework. Apparently lightweightness is relative - in Spring's case lighter than a full Java EE application server.

Comment: It's never just a few SQL inserts into Oracle.  Ever. *SIGH*  Hibernate gives you expandability options.

Comment: @Esko, Spring is said to be lightweight because using one component does not force you to use others, often your code doesn't have much of a dependency on Spring; the weight of what Spring forces onto you is very light

Answer (score 7):

You could get away with using just spring and [spring-JDBC integration](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html). Depending on the complexity of your data-access needs it may be more than enough. The spring [Object-relation mapping](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html) is also worth looking into if you're going to do a lot of data-access.

The nice thing about spring is that it's a very loosely coupled framework. So you can read up on the bits you use, and forget the rest - even in the runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Spring and Hibernate are really intended to do two different things.  Spring is first and foremost an inversion-of-control container and configuration subsystem, while Hibernate is a database binding and lazy loading engine.  If you don't want to introduce a bunch of new stuff into your code, stick with Spring and roll your own queries or use [iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/) to do much simpler database binding.

Comment: Don't confuse him with iBatis, IMHO. Its indeed a good framework, but yet another for him. No negatives for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is insert sql for oracle I would stick to a simple JDBC library. All you need is a Connection and maybe some ConnectionPool (maybe c3po). Hibernate and the like are too big/too complicated and IMO inferior. Hibernate incorporates JDBC under the hood but in every measurable way is inferior -- harder to use, not faster, and the queries you have to write or not any easier. It is also a testament to their inferiority because HQL also provides a bypass route so you can enter JDBC queries directly. They provide this (I suspect) because for any complex query you simply can't construct it well in HQL.